# Grails 2.4 Include jquery-ui

Tags: jquery-ui, grails, asset-pipeline

My grails application is using jquery-ui and twitter bootstrap plugin. I use the default application.js structure. Then I add the following line to include the jquery-ui and bootstrap.js :

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
...
```

The bootstrap.js in loaded properly, but the jquery-ui.js is not included.

Comment: And jquery loaded propely too?
Verify that your directories has right names.
Also you can try `require_tree` instead of `require`

Comment: Where do you placed `jquery-ui`? In the `./grails-app/assets/...` or in the `./web-app/...` ?

Comment: Thx wwarlock. Yes, the jquery loaded properly too. No I dont put the jquery-ui files, I use the jquery-ui plugin. I think the correct answer is because jquery-ui plugin 1.10.3 has no directive (Mario David's answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the [jquery-ui grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui), it is not included, because the current version has no directive file under `grails-app/assets/jquery-ui`. Instead it uses the `web-app` directory, to put the javascript files in the subfolder `jquery-ui/js` as you see in the [sources](https://github.com/gpc/grails-jquery-ui/tree/master/web-app/jquery-ui).

In order to get `jquery-ui` working you have to put the following line in your directive file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min
//= require bootstrap
```

In bootstrap it works out of the box, because they use a directive file under `grails-app/assets/javascript` as you see [here](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js).

Comment: Yes I use jquery-ui plugin, jquery plugin and twitter bootstrap plugin. Then which one is better using directive or using <asset:javascript src="jquery-ui.js"/> ?

Comment: adding jquery-ui to the directive file is the better one, because it all gets loaded via one http request. This is because all entries in the directive file will be combined to just one file, that is referenced via html. Depending on you use case, another approach could be to not host jquery / jquery-ui at all by yourself, and let a cdn do the whole work. this makes a lot of sence, if you are a public side. For more information see here: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: Worked for me with //= require js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom

Comment: For some reason I had to remove jquery-ui path from you example to make it work, e.g.: //= require js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require ../jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

I had to use the above declaration because of the jquery-ui plugin structure. You can see the same under plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.4/web-app/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js 
Actually the path referenced by jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js came out to be <project-name>/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js 
which is wrong and that is why you had to go a level up.

Answer (score 11):

I had to use the following settings (for these versions):

**grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy**

```
compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
runtime ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
```

**grails-app/assets/javascripts/foobar.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom
```

**grails-app/assets/stylesheets/foobar.css**

```
/*
*= require themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

this line also worked for me :

```
  //= require jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min
```